# Python, How not to pass a keyword argument to a method when the argument is None?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I wrote two example codes which share a same pattern.

As you can read below, I used if statement to not to pass keyword argument down to a sub function if the argument is None.
I want to do it in a better way.

Please share your thoughts if you have an idea.

```
# example_1
def mysort(alist, key=None):
    if key is None:
        alist = sorted(alist)
    else:
        alist = sorted(alist, key=key)

    return alist

# example_2
def create_index(index_name, mapping=None):
    es = Elasticsearch()
    if mapping in None:
        response = es.indices.create(index=index_name)
    else:
        response = es.indices.create(index=index_name, body=mapping)
    return respone
```

Comment: is there a typo in `if mapping in None:`? I guess it should read **is** None

Answer (score 0):

For the first example the default value for `key` is `None`, so you can just pass it directly:

```
# example_1
def mysort(alist, key=None):
    alist = sorted(alist, key=key)
    return alist
```

You can also setup a different default value. For instance the new default value of `123` would be passed to `sorted`.

```
# example_1
def mysort(alist, key=some_key):
    alist = sorted(alist, key=key)
    return alist
```

Comment: surely just `def mysort(alist, key=123)` for the 2nd case, assuming non-mutable value of the key

Comment: Or `mysort = functools.partial(sorted,key=123)` (not that using an integer key makes much sense)

Answer (score 0):

The default value of the parameter `key` of the function [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) is `None`. Because of this, your first `if`/`else` is not necessary. Simple use

```
alist = sorted(alist, key=key)
```

Use the default value of `body` of `es.indices.create` as the default value for `mapping` in your function `create_index`. Then you can get rid of the `if`/`else` in this function, too.

**Edit:** The [documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.create) says:

> body – The document

Try to find out if this is a JSON string or a Python dictionary that represents the document. In the JSON string case, use the string `"{}"`as the default value:

```
def create_index(index_name, mapping="{}"):
```

**Edit 2:** Using an empty dict would not work (see link in comment). So in the second case, you would have to use `if`/`else`.

Comment: careful with `mapping={}`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank   Thank your for your insights on my question.
You're right.  If a default value for a keyword argument is None, I don't need to use if-else statement. 
And in other cases I could find what the default value is and put it in my wapper function.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, for sorted, you are basically just packing the original function. I don't think you can avoid the `if` for the second example, but you can shorten it a little.

```
def create_index(index_name, mapping=None):
    kwargs = {'index': index_name}
    if mapping is not None:
        kwargs['body'] = mapping
    return Elasticsearch().indices.create(**kwargs)
```